# Function only excuting with debugger after creation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Visual Studio 2013 project, ASP MVC 4 to be more specific.

I am working on some dynamics multiple selects, the should be filled with the selected options when I chose a value on the parent select.

It only works when I apply a debugger line to the top of the function.

Here is fSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qtuxtrmL/

Here is the function with the issue

```
function SetSelectedValues(elem)
    {
        debugger;
        var combo = "#serial" + String(elem);
        $(combo + ' option').each(function () {
            var valor = $(this).attr('value');
            var existe = jQuery.inArray(valor, serialsy);
            console.log(existe);
            //console.log(serialsx);
            if (String(existe) == '-1') {
                console.log('Existe');
                $(combo + ' option[value="' + valor + '"]').prop("selected", true);
            }
        });
    }
```

And here is the behavior on a video ;) https://youtu.be/HHv2JMalArg

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: What version of IE you are using?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Firefox 37.0.2  Chrome 42.0.2311.90 dev-m and IE does not work for me

Comment: Hmm... (IE8- what would cause `console` to throw in such case)... Do you see any errors in console when *not debugging*?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov not, not a single error as you can see on the video

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov tried to add some json to simulate database ajax call, but it gives me some issues https://jsfiddle.net/qtuxtrmL/9/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the issue is that I had a call with asyc: false instead of async: false, so the call was asynchronous, because a spelling mistake, and I am very disappointed of jquery for not showing me any error for that